# Restricting access to files on an external drive

Tags: command-line, permissions, files, osx

I was wondering how to restrict access to a specific drive in Unix on the Mac. I was thinking to do this in Terminal where I create a file like this `mkfile 6k secure_access`. And where secure_access will be on the external drive and will only allow a specific user to be allowed to access the drive, thereby preventing other users from accessing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an encrypted disk image on your external drive, which will require a password to mount.  As long as you don't give out the password, other users will not be able to mount the image.  See: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1578 for details.

Basically, you use `Disk Utility` located in the `Applications -> Utilities` folder to create a new disk image, give it a name, a size, and then in the `Encryption` dialog, select an encryption type.

Disk Utility will then prompt you for a password which you must use to mount the disk image.

Comment: the link is broken though.

Comment: @Ravin455 strange, it works for me.

Comment: @Ravin455 in any case, I updated my answer to include a summary of the needed steps.

Comment: yeah i just tried the link again and now it works.